# Including header row of a SQL Server table using python

Tags: python, sql-server

How can I include the header row of a specific table in a given SQL Server database?

Here is my code. It currently only prints out the table records without the header row.

```
db_cursor = conn.cursor() 
qry = 'select * from ' +tbname
db_cursor.execute(qry)
table_rows2 = db_cursor.fetchall()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(table_rows2)
print(df2)
```

Here is the current output:

```
                                            0
0  [1, Resfo , Technology, Telecommunication]
1  [2, ATT , Technology, Social media]
2  [3, Airtel , Technology, Telecommunication]
```

Expected Output:

```
    SurveyID SurveyName   Sector     Category
0   1        Resfo        Technology  Telecommunication
1   2        ATT          Technology  Social media
2   3        Airtel       Technology  Telecommunication
```

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the [`description`](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Cursor#description) property on the `cursor` object, which is documented as:

> **description**
>
> This read-only attribute is a list of 7-item tuples, one tuple for each column returned by the last SQL select statement. Each tuple contains:
>
> 1. column name (or alias, if specified in the SQL)
> 2. type code
> 3. display size (pyodbc does not set this value)
> 4. internal size (in bytes)
> 5. precision
> 6. scale
> 7. nullable (True/False)
>
> This attribute will be None for operations that do not return rows or if one of the execute methods has not been called. The 'type code' value is the class type used to create the Python objects when reading rows. For example, a varchar column's type will be `str`.

To retrieve the list of column names in the current rowset you would use something like `column_names = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.description]` such as in the following example:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
conn = pyodbc.connect(
    'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};' +
    'SERVER=tcp:sql2019,1433;' +
    'UID=sa;' +
    'PWD=StrongPassw0rd;' +
    'DATABASE=msdb;'
)
cursor = conn.cursor() 
cursor.execute('select * from sys.database_files')
column_names = [tup[0] for tup in cursor.description]
table_rows = cursor.fetchall()
df2 = pd.DataFrame(table_rows)
print(column_names)
print(df2)
```

Which prints the output:

```
['file_id', 'file_guid', 'type', 'type_desc', 'data_space_id', 'name', 'physical_name', 'state', 'state_desc', 'size', 'max_size', 'growth', 'is_media_read_only', 'is_read_only', 'is_sparse', 'is_percent_growth', 'is_name_reserved', 'is_persistent_log_buffer', 'create_lsn', 'drop_lsn', 'read_only_lsn', 'read_write_lsn', 'differential_base_lsn', 'differential_base_guid', 'differential_base_time', 'redo_start_lsn', 'redo_start_fork_guid', 'redo_target_lsn', 'redo_target_fork_guid', 'backup_lsn']
                                                   0
0  [1, 9CD66F90-8F5D-4A21-9378-86BE7A1B2CFF, 0, R...
1  [2, 846D0789-0659-4EE1-9139-74548FBE90A7, 1, L...
```